# How to apply the Theme in iOS Native apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, themes

I am creating a native application in which I want to implement the theme setting.
I have one setting tab where the user can choose any theme.

But when the user select any theme how do I change all the UI, depending on the theme.

1- I have to restart the app from the beginning. When doing this should I use to push user to MainController? And in all the controllers in viewdidLoad I change the theme.

2- Or any other method I have to use please suggest the correct way.

Comment: do you have this setting tan accessing across application, or you at specific screen or in setting bundle?

Comment: by theme what i understand is background view/ background color, correct?

Comment: background view/ background color,NavigationBar color,Tabbar color and text colour,buttons all things.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of your question -

1- I have to restart the app from beginning for doing this should i use to push user to MainController. and in all the controllers in viewdidLoad i change the theme.

No. You won't need to do that, as you only have to change look and feel of the app.

2- Or any other method i have to USe Please suggest me what is the correct way.

In Controllers of your app try setting color of elements in `viewWillAppear`, and all these colours are fetched from `NSUserDefaults` or any other place from where you want.
When user change theme, just change the color which is stored in `NSUserDefaults` or any other place, and reload only that controller with the help of utility methods. Rest view controller will automatically gets changes when they will be loaded.

Utility Class will take the responsibility to change the color of UI Element, might be you need to create 2 or 3 utility methods for this purpose.

Hope it clear some doubts.

Comment: Yes @Rishi you are right but i have one more doubt if i use NSUserDefaults then it affect the performance of the app coz i have more params to change the theme ??????

Comment: it will depend what all data you are going to store, if you are storing some color and string value, then it will not effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-theme your app depending on what the user selects, I recommend a dynamic styling library like http://nativecss.com/

It let's you retheme your app whilst the app is running, which sounds like what you are after!